# Variable-width hanging indents in vim?

Tags: vim

This isn't a programming question *per se*, since I'm aiming to use this for note-taking -- but there just isn't any community more reliable for in-depth vim knowledge than this one.

What I'd like to do is set a hanging indent in vim - you know, the kind that looks like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
  adipisicing elit neque amet fuga
  dolores voluptatem aspernatur
  explicabo quasi. Nostrum...
```

Except I know you can do this with

```
set formatoptions+=2
```

What I'd really like is for vim to automatically set the width of the indent based on the presence of a special character in the first line. For instance, I might want to set this special character to ":" to format my text like so:

```
Lorem: Ipsum porro dolorem nostrum 
       incidunt similique a? Eaque 
       minus aliquid dolorem veritatis 
       omnis odit. 
Quidem: distinctio quibusdam distinctio 
        accusamus alias magnam. 
Voluptatem: dignissimos exercitationem 
            deleniti aliquam ratione? 
            Necessitatibus expedita 
            praesentium.
```

In my ideal scenario, this would also be compatible with vim's `breakindent` setting, which visually indents soft-wrapped lines (officially included in vim as of patch 7.4.338).

Does anyone know if this is possible - or even if this functionality can be achieved with a plugin?

Comment: Sounds like you want the `n` format option, which doesn't play well with `2` ([help fo-table](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#fo-table)).

Comment: Sorry, just clarified in the text of the question that I'd like it to work with auto-indenting of soft-wrapped lines via `breakindent`.

Comment: Is that mutually exclusive with `set fo+=2n`? From what I can see, `2` pretty much requires autoindent anyway. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still phrasing my question wrong. `set fo+=2n` does create my desired formatting, but only on a hard wrap. I want the same behavior on a soft wrap. `breakindent` supports basic softwrap indentation, and `breakindentopt=shift:{n}` supports adjusting the indentation level by a fixed number. It looks like this feature is not implemented yet, and if it were, it would belong as a parameter of `breakindentopt`.